# SATA to USB Adapter

Tags: usb, hard-drive, sata

A friend of mine had a problem with his computer and it no longer works. We just want to get the data from the HDD but are unable to do so. We have tried connecting the HDD to my Ubuntu machine with this [SATA to USB Converter](http://www.amazon.de/Delock-Konverter-SATA-Stecker-Power/dp/B005OMXBN2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1441726017&sr=8-1&keywords=delock%20usb%20sata). When I connect it to my machine, the drive doesn't show up in the file manager.

"lsusb" shows that the converter gets detected.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASMedia 2105 SATA bridge
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:5606 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've tried to mount it like in [another post](http://Bus%20001%20Device%20002:%20ID%208087:8000%20Intel%20Corp.%20%20Bus%20001%20Device%20001:%20ID%201d6b:0002%20Linux%20Foundation%202.0%20root%20hub%20Bus%20003%20Device%20002:%20ID%20174c:55aa%20ASMedia%20Technology%20Inc.%20ASMedia%202105%20SATA%20bridge%20Bus%20003%20Device%20001:%20ID%201d6b:0003%20Linux%20Foundation%203.0%20root%20hub%20Bus%20002%20Device%20002:%20ID%200bda:5606%20Realtek%20Semiconductor%20Corp.%20%20Bus%20002%20Device%20001:%20ID%201d6b:0002%20Linux%20Foundation%202.0%20root%20hub), but that doesn't work either. So anybody have any ideas of how I can mount the HDD?

Comment: Forgive the question, but did you plug in _both_ USB connectors...?

Comment: You want to check if only the USB adapter is recognized or the hard drive as well. Look around the output of dmesg and see if you find messages about the adapter and the attached hdd.

Comment: Is the drive in question a 2.5 inch or 3.5 inch hard drive?  If it is the latter, you won't be able to power up the drive using only the SATA to USB converter.

Comment: When plugging in the drive to your computer, are you able to hear the HDD turn on? You should be able to hear the drive spinning. If there is no sound coming from the drive then you may need to get a USB to SATA converter that comes with a power supply, or the drive might be completely dead. If you type ``sudo fdisk -l`` do you see the drive listed?

Comment: Are you sure the drive is ok since the friend "had a problem with his computer"?

Answer (score 1):

I would not be surprised if the adapter is somehow faulty.  The use of a second USB cord to get power violates the USB specifications and anyone that can't be bothered to follow this very basic USB specification is quite likely to violate some other specification.

I'd suggest returning the adapter if you can and getting one that powers the drive properly.  That would be with a single USB plug for power and data, or with USB for data and a connection to a wall outlet for power.

Answer (score 0):

I HAD the same problem.

1) Restart your pc + login
2) Plug in the USB
3) Type "lsusb" in the terminal
4) WAIT for ASMedia to show up
5) Look at your file explorer and WAIT
6) KEEP WAITING for 5 minutes.

If the hard disk still doesn't show up, repeat (I had to do it approx. 20x).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a desktop (i am), you can plug the hard drive into your motherboard using a sata cable and reboot (don't forget sata power then :) ). I had a much harder hard drive where this worked to get it show up in the disk list using "Disks". If the hard drive is still working, you don't have to reboot, sata is hot-pluggable.